# use two radgridview to display data

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I create `radlistview1` contains `radlistview2`.

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="cg_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            thong tin loai
            <telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="cg_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("cg_id") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>        
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT cg_id, cg_name, cg_size, cg_soluongcay, cg_tongtichluydai FROM Categorys_Group WHERE (cg_id = @id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="id" DefaultValue='1' />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categorys_Group]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you see. radlistview2 use SqlDataSource2. Now, i want to asp:SessionParameter  defaultvalue with value get from radlistview1 (<%#Eval("cg_id") %>), But it error.

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="id" DefaultValue='<%#Eval("cg_id") %>' />
```

my target is use 2 radlistview. `radlistview1` contain `radlistview2`. `radlistview2` will display data with id gotten `radlistview1`.

who can help me?

Thank you for your read .

Comment: Is there any error here ? I suggest , you should better write both of your `sqldatasourse` outside of your `listView` !

Comment: I don't sqldatasourse2 outside radlistview1. Because i want to set value Session["id"] = get value of radlistview1 every time radlistview1 create item.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SqlDataSource2` as

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"  
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>"  
 SelectCommand='SELECT cg_id, cg_name, cg_size, cg_soluongcay, cg_tongtichluydai  
                FROM Categorys_Group WHERE (cg_id = <%# Eval("cg_id") %>)' >
```

this code will not need to use `sessionParameter` .

**or**

If you want to use parameter , change your `sessionParameter` to `Parameter` likes

```
<asp:Parameter  DefaultValue='<%# Eval("cg_id") %>)' Type="Int32" Name="id"/>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: the first I thanks for help me. I do 2 ways but both have an error. in code will not need to use sessionParameter . Error : Incorrect syntax near '<'.  And code other: <asp:Parameter  DefaultValue='<%# Eval("cg_id") %>)' Type="Int32" Name="id"/> error : Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: Why defaultvalue of  <asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="id" DefaultValue='<%#Eval("cg_id") %>' /> don't get value <%#Eval("cg_id") %> when change <%#Eval("cg_id") %> to 1 or 2 ... it successful.